# Merging a git revert -m into the master branch

Tags: git, merge

I had the following situation

```
M--o--o------------------
    \ \
     \ B-----------------
      \
       C-----------------
```

I did some modifications on the branch B and C. At a certain point I thought it would be good to pull the merge B into the merge C. Let's say the changesets 1,2,3 of branch B were pulled into C.

I then decided to revert this merge, using "git revert -m"

I did again some commits in both branches. Then I merged branch C into M.
Finally I merged B into M.

Result: changesets 1,2,3 are not included in M.

Is there any error with this procedure? Could it be a bug?

Comment: Incomprehensible. There is no such thing as a changeset in git. “Pull” does not mean anything in this context. Also your diagram is meaningless (what is the stuff to the right of B and C?), and you did not show us any real git commands you gave.

Comment: I believe he means `commit` when he says `changeset` and `merge` when he says `pull changes`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a picture of your situation:

```
M--o--o------------------------M1-M2   <----Branch M
\ \                            /  /
 \ B--1-2-3--4----------------/---     <----Branch B
  \         \                /
   C---------MC--R(revert)---          <----Branch C
```

When you merge B into M, git will include only commit 4 and onward in the merge into M.  This is because 1,2,3 are already in C which has already been merged, and there is no reason to add them again.  Since C reverts these, the result in M will be that 1,2,3 are effectively not included in M.

Note that reverting merge commits in git is not straightforward.  Reverting a merge does not actually "undo the merge". But it does remove the content added by that merge. If you need to revert a merge, you will need to keep in mind that future merges will possibly need manual intervention to correct those future merges.